# Flutter : which url format that videp_player package support for play video?

Tags: flutter, flutter-video-player

I'm new in programming and I'm studying Flutter, I tried to play video by video_player package, I tried 3 urls play ing video such as :

> 1.https://vt.tiktok.com/ZSdKGyP6j/?k=1
>
> 2.https://flutter.github.io/assets-for-api-docs/assets/videos/butterfly.mp4
>
> 3.http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4

Just number 2 is working, I don't understand why. Please explain it to me

Answer (score 0):

In android, it uses exo player. below formats are supported.

https://exoplayer.dev/supported-formats.html